# AspNet Identity 2.0 Email and UserName duplication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

My current Asp.Net MVC 5 project mandates *Email address* for *UserName*. Now I want to *upgrade* ASPNet Identity v1.0 to *v2.0* to leverage all its new features ([see here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/20/test-announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0.aspx)).

However, ASPNet Identity v2.0 adds *Email* as a separate column to the *Users* table and adds a corresponding property to the *IdentityUser* class.

I don't want to duplicate *UserName* into this new *Email* column. How can I *map* this Email Property of IdentityUser to use existing UserName column & property? Is it possible to *ignore* this Email property and skip adding the column in the Users table? Has anybody tried this?

Please share.

**Update**

This is the identity 2.0 limitation. We cannot ignore Email property or leave it Null. Some of the Identity functionality will not work. :(

Comment: I am able to make this work by implementing my own User class that just inherits from IUser<TKey>, and implementing UserManger, UserStore.

Comment: @santhosh can you please look this question and tel me the suggestion ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929767/asp-net-identity-entity-framework-database-first-approach-with-own-table-definti

Answer (score 4):

You can try one of these:

1. Try to ignore it by either overriding `Email` property in your `User` class and unmapping it or using fluent API.

   ```
   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
   {
     // ....

     [NotMapped]
     public override string Email { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Ignore(u => u.Email);
   }
   ```
2. When you register your user just make sure that you populate `Email` with your `UserName`

   ```
   public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
           // ...
       }
   }
   ```

Of course, you can always ignore `Email` column if you're not going to use it, since it allows NULLs, it'll just be sitting in your `AspNetUsers` table with bunch of NULLs, not the best approach but remember that by ignoring it you might lose new features that ASP.NET Identity 2 might offer that you might want to use.

**NOTE** However I'm not sure if option number 1 will work on `Email` property since it's probably used all over the place in new Identity code. Worth a try though. I know that's how you can get rid of other columns if you don't need them. I personally happen to use new `Email` property/column so I haven't tried it.

Not sure if it helps you, but thought I'd share it just in case.

Comment: I had already tried your option 1 which did not work. (InvalidOperationException: The property 'Email' is not a declared property on type 'ApplicationUser'. Verify that the property has not been explicitly excluded from the model by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Make sure that it is a valid primitive property.)
Your option 2 is already shown in the samples (check nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples). I would prefer not to have Email column in the Users table and so the question!

Comment: @Santosh Point is that lots of Identity code is strongly-coupled with the `email`-column thus removing it may break more than you realise - certainly that's not what you want since we're talking about security. And let's be honest, one unused NULL column will never be the bottleneck in your app performance ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, and the way that I resolved it was that the email address was the same as the username when creating a user:

```
var newUser = new ApplicationUser()
{
    UserName = email,
    Email = email,
};
```

However, if you try to create an account with a duplicate username, you will get 2 validation errors, one for the username field, and one for the email address.

To get around that, allow email addresses to not be unique (they will still be unique though as your usernames are unique) by editing the identityconfig.cs file:

```
manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = false
            };
```